# In MySql, how can you Prepare and Execute a Create Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, execute, prepare

I'm attempting to create a MySql Stored Procedure via a Prepare/ Execute statement and I'm getting a error.  I don't understand what Syntax I'm breaking.

```
SET @SourceDBName='dev';
    SET @alterstatement=CONCAT('DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE ',@SourceDBName,'.execute_statement (alterstatement VARCHAR (767)) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @alterstatement; 
        PREPARE executionstatement FROM @alterstatement; 
        EXECUTE executionstatement;
        END //');
    SELECT @alterstatement;
    PREPARE executionstatement FROM @alterstatement;
    EXECUTE executionstatement;
```

I get a generic syntax error:

```
09:43:20    PREPARE executionstatement FROM @alterstatement Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //         CREATE PROCEDURE dev.execute_statement (alterstatement VARC' at line 1    0.086 sec
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I've tried troubleshooting, but I haven'y figured it out yet.

Comment: `DELIMITER` is a command of the official command-line utility. You can't use it elsewhere.

Comment: So you can't create a Stored Procedure with Execute then?

Comment: I was typing a proper answer while you were reading this.

Answer (score 1):

`DELIMITER` is a command of the official [command-line utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html). You can't use it elsewhere.

In your case, you don't need it anyway. The [`PREPARE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html) does not accept multiple statements:

> The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.

... so there's no need for separators. However, you'll get this error:

> This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

... because `CREATE PROCEDURE` is apparently [not supported yet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html#idm139900891219312):

> The following SQL statements can be used as prepared statements:
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> {CREATE | DROP} INDEX
> {CREATE | RENAME | DROP} DATABASE
> {CREATE | DROP} TABLE
> {CREATE | RENAME | DROP} USER
> {CREATE | DROP} VIEW
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!